# Using the input of a Lambda expression as an index for a separate array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

I'm currently trying to make a calculator that calculates Mean / Median / IQR / Standard Deviation / Variance of a set of data and a set of frequencies. To get the Mean of a set of data, i had intended to use the Sum() function and Lambda expressions, however i ran into a problem with this code below.

```
public double stat_getMeanGrouped(double[] dataset, double[] frequency)
{
    return dataset.Sum(x => x * frequency[int.Parse(x.toString)] / (double)frequency.Sum();
}
```

`stat_getMeanGrouped(new double[] {1,2,3}, new double[] {1,1,1});`
should return 2
however returns an index outside of range exception.

I understand why the error is happening, i just need help amending it.

Comment: `int.Parse(x.toString)`?! Eeeehm, what? Just cast to int: `(int)x`.

Comment: my brain is hardly functioning at the minute, just want to get this piece of coding done, but that does make me feel stupid

Comment: I have no clue what the purpose of `dataset` is. You're using it to access `frequencies` by index, however indeices start at zero instead of one. So the first element is `frequencies[0]`. Maybe you just need to substract one from `x`?

Comment: What i'm trying to do here is multiply dataset[i] by frequency[i] then divide by the sum of frequency to get the mean, then i can use that in the variance / standard deviation calculations. I think i'm just going to stick to a for loop though, makes it so much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the index, you can get it from the `Select` overload, if you want to use LINQ:

```
public static double stat_getMeanGrouped(double[] dataset, double[] frequency)
{
    return dataset
        .Select((value, index) => (Value: value, Index: index))
        .Where(x => x.Index < frequency.Length) // just to be sure
        .Sum(x => x.Value * frequency[x.Index]) / (double)frequency.Sum();
}
```